# Can "author" be used to refer to the creator of a non-literary work?

Tags: meaning

I referred to the creator of a hardware device as the "author" of it earlier. Thinking back on it, I feel embarrassed for using "author" instead of "inventor" or "creator" or anything other than "author". To me, "author" is very much associated with writing/typing things, rather than coming up with this electronic device. But then I tried looking it up, to make myself possibly feel better, and I just find this ambiguous: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/author

> 1. The originator or creator of a work, especially of a literary composition.

"Especially" here could mean "specifically" or "primarily". (Unless I'm mistaken about that as well.)

Can "author" be used as I used it, or did that just reveal to the receiver that I'm a poor English speaker whose overall message cannot be taken seriously?

Comment: What about using the expression “hardware designer”?   See https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hardware%20designer%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2007,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: @user66974 Sure, but now I'm asking about "author" since the "damage" is already done.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/author) has: *A writer of a book, article, or document* but can also mean *An originator of a plan or idea.* A device is more usually developed by an **engineer**.

Comment: There are of course non-central usages ... 'the author of his own downfall' / 'Be the Author of Your Own Success' ....  But this sounds distinctly unnatural. A 'work (of art, fiction ... even one's lifework)' and an 'electronic device' are poles apart.

Comment: Does *creator of a work* mean any work? Must mean something as a written work, not a ditch dug or gadget.

Comment: You've only to look at how common the words [***the author of his own misfortune***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+author+of+his+own+misfortune%22) occur in Google Books to answer this one.

Comment: @FF The title question, yes. Not the one about the narrower usage.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first have a dictionary definition, that from the OALD.

> ([OALD 2](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/author_1?q=author) the person who creates or starts something, especially a plan or an idea

In spite of the definition, "author" is a term associated with a wide range of actions: crimes, remarks, decisions, laws, designs, thoughts, actions,

For such realizations as constructions (of all sorts), the word "author" does not seem to be idiomatic at all; this finds support in a few ngrams.

[ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=author+of+the+machine%2C+author+of+the+building%2C+author+of+the+construction&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20construction%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20construction%3B%2Cc0) (research: "author of the machine,author of the building,author of the construction", [ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=author+of+the+device&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cauthor%20of%20the%20device%3B%2Cc0) (author of the device); the occurrences shown in the ngrams are false positives: [author of the machine](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22author%20of%20the%20machine%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [author of the building](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22author%20of%20the%20building%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [author of the construction](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22author%20of%20the%20construction%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [author of the device](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22author%20of%20the%20device%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)
The same results are obtained for "author of the house", "author of the engine" and "author of the robot". This seems to confirm that "author" is not used with words that connote some sort of physical construction. Nor has been  "author of the theory"  used at all (two cases of "author of a theory" in the books), although those phrases do sound idiomatic; instead are found a few "inventor of the theory" and a lot of "creator of the theory".

However, if one considers the design of various physically constructed things, it becomes possible to speak of "*the author of the design*". So, for engines, robots, machines, etc., houses, buildings, and so on, one may use "the author of" in this way.

Comment: I have only ever seen "author" used to describe the creator of something that is, or ostensibly *could be* written down in some way. I agree someone could author a design, idea, remark, or plan even if they don't actually write it down. But I don't see how someone could be the author of a house, or the author of a robbery, or the author of the telephone, for example. One could perhaps be the author *of the design* of those things, but not the author of those things themselves.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That is not what I mean; "the author of a house" is not idiomatic at all as far as I know. What I mean is this: in a discussion about (for instance) a house, you can use "the author of the design of the house", and most often you can do away with "of the house" and say "the author of the design" or  "the author of its design".

Comment: OP is concerned agout 'the author of this electronic device' (I'm thinking say burglar alarm)..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is as for "construction"; one will never speak, for instance of the "authors of an IC";  the word "designers" and "design" will be used in that context, which is analogous to  building in architecture; machines are often said to be fabricated or _constructed_ (after they have been conceived).  I think a burglar alarm might even be called a machine, so vast is the scope of application of this word (a computer is sometimes called a machine); in any case there is no problem with  "device"; "design of a device" has to be idiomatic (provided the device is not too simple).

Comment: But 'the author of a burglar alarm' gets zero hits on Google, as I'd expect and hope.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The fact that something is not found through Google is no proof of its invalidity (possibly nobody has had so far any need for the particular concept investigated). However, that is not the point: of course, I agree with you that  "author of a burglar alarm" is not idiomatic, but "author of _the design_ of a burglar alarm" _is_. This is just as the reasoning for "house" in my comment following   user Nuclear Hoagie's  above (the first in the series).

Comment: OP is obviously, expressly, asking about whether instead of using say 'the inventor of the laser printer' one may without fear of sounding inexpert use 'the author of the laser printer'. Not 'the author of the idea that a laser device could be used in a printer'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth More is involved than the idea and I do not retain the concept of idea; what corresponds here is the _design_, which is the creation. My answer is, in a few words,  "No, 'author of the printer' is not idiomatic, and the best to still  use 'author' in a pertinent way is to shift the problem to the level of  a concept that is inseparable of creation, that concept being the design.".  The author of the design is the designer, is the creator.

Comment: It's certainly valid to use a suboptimal (now closed) question as a springboard for a sensible debate; hence editing. But (1) OP's focused question should if possible be clearly answered first (here, 'No') and (2) supporting references should be given (for the ultra-wide title question, 'the author of his own downfall' can probably be found as an example sentence in a dictionary, for starters).